# Don't save this request http in database on django

Tags: django, database, python-3.x, http

Client:
I send my post on django

```
import requests
payload = {'datax':['12', '15'], 'datay':['22', '23'], 'timestamp':['1', '2'], 'data':['20', '19'], 'timestamp1':['1', '2'], 'mission':['Mission01', 'Mission01']}
r = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000", data=payload)
```

Server(Django): I receive http post from client and i save data on database.
This my models
home/models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Mission(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + '-' + self.description

class SensorLog (models.Model):
    mission = models.ForeignKey(Mission, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    data = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    timestamp = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class PositionLog(models.Model):
    mission = models.ForeignKey(Mission, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    datax = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    datay = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    timestamp = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

this my view
home/view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from .models import Mission, SensorLog, PositionLog

@csrf_exempt
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.POST.getlist('datax')
        datass = request.POST.getlist('datay')
        timestampss = request.POST.getlist('timestamp')
        datas = request.POST.getlist('data')
        timestamps = request.POST.getlist('timestamp1')
        missions = request.POST.getlist('mission')
        for i in range(len(data)):
            mission = Mission.objects.get(name=missions[i])
            post1 = PositionLog.objects.create(datax=data[i], datay=datass[i], timestamp=timestampss[i], mission=mission)
            post = SensorLog.objects.create(data=datas[i], timestamp=timestamps[i], mission=mission)
    return HttpResponse()

def index(request):
    all_mission = Mission.objects.all()
    context = {'all_mission': all_mission}
    return render(request, 'mission/index.html', context)

def detail(request, mission_id):
    try:
        mission = Mission.objects.get(pk=mission_id)
    except Mission.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Mission dose not exist")
    return render(request, 'mission/detail.html', {'mission': mission})
```

my urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from home import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home, name ='home'),
    path('mission/', include('home.urls'))
]
```

and this in my urls in my home/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [

    #/mission/
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),

    #/mission/712/
    url(r'(?P<mission_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
]
```

I receve my http post but not save data. i have ("POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 0)
why not save the data? where is my error?

Comment: Do you have logs, errors, debug information, what have you tried, have you identified the section of code that does not work, how do you know that the data is not saved (only through your view or you can confirm through a django admin tool), ...

Comment: Can you post your `urls.py`?

Comment: Yes, I have add above my urls.py

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you're passing lists of values as the payload of `requests.post()`, but multiple values should not be passed in this way with regular form encoded post requests. The square brackets do not translate into lists by the time the data reaches the view.

If you wish to keep the same data structure, you'd need to switch to sending the payload as JSON by specifying the `json` argument:

```
r = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000", json=payload)  # Use json
```

In your view, you'd then need to load the JSON payload, and retrieve each list with a regular `get()`:

```
import json

@csrf_exempt
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Load the JSON payload
        payload = json.loads(request.body)

        # Retrieve the lists
        data = payload.get('datax')
        datass = payload.get('datay')
        timestampss = payload.get('timestamp')
        datas = payload.get('data')
        timestamps = payload.get('timestamp1')
        missions = payload.get('mission')
        ...
```